# BadImageFormatException in IIS on x64

Tags: 64-bit, iis-7.5, badimageformatexception

I am using Windows 7 x64. I get a BadImageFormatException when starting a MVC app. If it runs in an application pool with 32-bit applications enabled the exception is not thrown. It looks like loading the global.asax is the problem. I enabled the fusion logging (HKLM\software\Microsft\Fusion!EnableLog) registry setting. This is the log:

```
    === Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
LOG: Where-ref bind. Location = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\spl.sim.mvc\5802065c\a2782d40\App_global.asax.olejmmua.dll
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Spl/SimSvn4.5/Source/Spl.Sim.Mvc/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Spl\SimSvn4.5\Source\Spl.Sim.Mvc\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Spl\SimSvn4.5\Source\Spl.Sim.Mvc\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/spl.sim.mvc/5802065c/a2782d40/App_global.asax.olejmmua.dll.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.
```

Using different build configurations this is the result:

Build x64,    32 bit application pool false: Error

Build x86,    32 bit application pool false: Error

Build AnyCPU, 32 bit application pool false: Error

Build x64,    32 bit application pool true: Error

Build x86,    32 bit application pool true: OK

Build AnyCPU, 32 bit application pool true: OK

IIS Express: OK

How can I find the 32 bit problem dll used in a 64 bit configuration?

Answer (score 6):

I found the problem. I used Instrumentation for profiling. This added the following lines to the web.config:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.AspNetHelper" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <codeBase version="11.0.0.0" href="file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio%2011.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.AspNetHelper.DLL" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

After removing this dependentAssembly from the web.config section the program is working as expected. I also removed the `assemblyPostProcessorType` attribute from the `compilation` element

Comment: Saved my day. But the problem with this is, I need to remove the dependent Assemblies on my development machine web.config and should rebuild the application.